# Why does it happen? about label of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=np.loadtxt("something.dat")
plt.plot(a[0,1:],a[10,1:],label=r"$10\ \mathrm{{sec}$")
plt.legend("upper right")
plt.show()
```

I tried plotting data but it cannot see the actual label.
I can see "p" or "u" on the figure.
Why does it happen?
My python is 3.6.6, also matplotlib is 2.2.2

Comment: Try adding `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)` and `plt.rc('font', family='serif')` before you plot, otherwise first try without a TeX expression as label (e.g. just `label="Test"`).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried your both suggestions but it doesn't work.

Comment: My bad... it should be `plt.legend(loc="upper right")` ;)

Comment: I already tried it.
But I can only see "p" or "u" on label.

Comment: When I use your code with random data and the `loc="upper right"` argument, I can see the correct label, could you post an example that is easier reproducible, i.e. w/o TeX and w/o external data dependency?